# Unable to locate and run Psi program

Tags: software-installation

I installed `Psi+` `XMPP` client on my `Ubuntu` machine like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:psi-plus/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install psi-plus psi-plus-plugins psi-plus-icons* psi-plus-l10n psi-plus-plugin-psimedia
```

But after all these commands I can not locate and run it.

Comment: What happen when you run `psi-plus` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the installed files via

```
dpkg -L psi-plus
```

Example output

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/psi-plus
/usr/share
/usr/share/psi-plus
/usr/share/psi-plus/psi-plus.xpm
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/psi-plus
/usr/share/doc/psi-plus/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/psi-plus/TODO.gz
/usr/share/doc/psi-plus/copyright
/usr/share/doc/psi-plus/README
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/psi-plus.desktop
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/psi-plus.1.gz
/usr/share/indicators
/usr/share/indicators/messages
/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications
/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/psi-plus
/usr/share/menu
/usr/share/menu/psi-plus
```

As you can see, you have exactly one binary:

```
/usr/bin/psi-plus
```

Therefore you can start the application in a terminal via

```
psi-plus
```

---

And you have a `desktop` file

```
/usr/share/applications/psi-plus.desktop
```

Therefore you could use Unity Dash/GNOME Activities, depends on your installed GUI

Open the application overview via <kbd>Super</kbd> and type `psi`

[image]